# IMG bigger than container, how can I center the image?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image that is bigger than the container in height, now I have overflow hidden which is ok, as I don't want the image to go out from the container. - The problem is that I want to at least get the center of the image to show rather than the top?

I know there is scrollTop but that scrolls everything including the buttons etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the image as background of the container with center position?

Comment: Do your images have a fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the image as the background of the container.

Like,

```
#container{
  background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Um..

I have a list of <img src="" /> as a slide show... I cannot set a static background image ;x

Comment: @user3451555 You can using some CSS tricks for that. Ref. http://css-tricks.com/slider-with-sliding-backgrounds/

Answer (score 2):

If you can use "position:absolute" or "position:fixed" with your code, you can simply use the CLIP property on the container. Please, look at [Clip property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" />
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" />
```

css:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 100px;
}
.container img {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: -240px 0 0 -320px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

margin -240px is the height of the image (480px) divided by 2, and margin -320px is the width of the image (640px) divided by 2.

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/P23Qj/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#container {
  background-image: url('path/to/your/image.xyz');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you have list of `<img>`'s as a slideshow, you can either replace `<img>` tags with `<div>`'s and use CSS above; or you have to adjust (resize) actual images.

Comment: Just so everyone is aware, IE8 and below doesn't support `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7dM8Z/)**

You can use max height as follows

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt=""></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{height:100px; border:1px solid red;}
.box img{max-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jQuery, so I'm going to have a jQuery solution for you.

CSS is amazing, but for dynamic heights etc it's difficult to get reliable results cross browser. My jQuery solution should be fairly simple and work well in most situations.

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eh5h8/

Container is 300px high, image is 500px high. The difference is calculated (200px) then divided by 2 so that we can offset it correctly to the center (100px).

You can take this example and apply it to your needs.

**HTML**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" width="500" height="500" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #eee;
}

#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

**jQuery (Remember to link to the jQuery library)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $container = $("#container"),
        $img = $container.find("img");

    if ( $img.height() > $container.height() ) {

        var difference = Math.round( ( $img.height() - $container.height() ) / 2);
        $img.css({ "margin-top" : "-" + difference + "px" });

    }

});
```

Good luck!